# Java - change focus on key press

Tags: java, eclipse, focus, swt, traversal

I am writing a Java Application for Data Entry using Eclipse and SWT. Naturally it has a great many Text objects.

What I would like to happen is that when user enters something into one field focus automatically changes to the next field.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
final Text textBox = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
textBox.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (x.getText().length() == 1); {
            x.traverse(SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Text textBox = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
textBox.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        if (textBox.getText().equals("") == false) {
            textBox.traverse(SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT);
        }
    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to have a look at the VerifyListener interface. See this interesting blog post for a caveat though: http://eclipsenuggets.blogspot.com/2008/10/eclipse-bug-patterns-selfish-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change the focus *after* the field has been filled.  I suggest using a DocumentListener (or whatever SWT calls it) to be notified of changes to the field's content: if it has the right number of characters, jump to the next field.